# iOS: strange behaviour with UIWebView and Base64-encoded image while generating a PDF

Tags: ios, image, pdf, uiwebview, base64

I've managed to load the following HTML string in a `UIWebView`. Both the text and the image are rendered correctly:

```
<b>Hello <i>World</i>!</b><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"/>
```

However, if I try to generate a PDF from this HTML string right after calling `loadHTMLString` on my UIWebView, the Base64-encoded image is not displayed in the UIWebView (nor in the PDF).

Here's the full code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let htmlString = "<b>Hello <i>World!</i></b><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"/>"

    // load HTML string into the UIWebView
    // works correctly if the code after this line is commented
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)

    /* Generate PDF and save it to file. */

    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlString)
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8)
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")

    let printable = CGRectInset(page, 0, 0)
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages() {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPageAtIndex(i - 1, inRect: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())file.pdf"
    pdfData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    print("open \(path)")
}
```

There are no warnings or error messages, so what's going on?

Comment: Did you found a way why base64 images were not rendered into PDF?

Comment: @Ramis Sadly, no...

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot of hours with same problem. ***Seems that UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter doesn't interpret correctly the base64 image nor the image loaded from local bundle.***
The only way I could render properly a PDF from an HTML was via UIWebView: once the UIWebView is loaded with yours HTML string, you have to use its UIViewPrinterFormatter as printerFormatter for your function which draws the PDF.

Here an example of my UIWebView's:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pdfRender = PdfRender()
    webView.loadHTMLString(pdfRender.renderPdfCard(wine: wine), baseURL: NSURL(string: pdfRender.pathTemplatePdf!)! as URL)
}
```

PdfRender is the class which performs the rendering from a HTML with placeholder (wine is my model object). The method ***renderPdfCard*** returns the full HTML as a String.

Here the UIWebViewDelegate to implement:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    if !webView.isLoading{
        pdfRender.exportHTMLContentToPDF(wine: wine, printFormatter: webView.viewPrintFormatter())
    }
}
```

And here, some methods from the class ***PdfRender***:

```
func exportHTMLContentToPDF(wine: Wine, printFormatter: UIViewPrintFormatter) {
    let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()
    printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
    let pdfData = self.drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: printPageRenderer)
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    pdfFilename = "\(documentsPath)/test.pdf"
    pdfData?.write(toFile: pdfFilename, atomically: true)

    print(pdfFilename)
}

func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
    let data = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: 0, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    return data
}
```

Code is updated to Swift 3.
Hope this may help!

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it works. However, I'll continue to look for a solution that works without using a UIWebView and that maybe can be used on both macOS and iOS :).

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to see that works for you. If you find that solution, please keep me updated